# Subtract two columns from two tables with Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 4 tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Branch(
  ID INT,
  Name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Branch VALUES 
(1,'A'), (2,'B');

CREATE TABLE Product(
  ID INT,
  Name VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Product VALUES 
(1,'X'), (2,'Y');

CREATE TABLE StockIn(
  ID INT,
  ProductId INT,
  Quantity INT,
  BranchId INT
);

INSERT INTO StockIn VALUES 
(1,1,10,1),
(2,1,20,1),
(3,1,50,2),
(4,1,10,2);

CREATE TABLE StockOut(
  ID INT,
  ProductId INT,
  Quantity INT,
  BranchId INT
);

INSERT INTO StockOut VALUES 
(1,1,5,1),
(2,1,21,1),
(3,1,45,2),
(4,1,5,2);
```

Now i want to calculate stock from these (StockIn-StockOut).

by using below query i got stockin and stockout from stock tables by grouping thier branches.

**StockIn**

```
select BranchId, ifnull(sum(Quantity),0) Quantity from stockin where productid=1 group by BranchId;
```

[image]

**StockOut**

```
select BranchId, ifnull(sum(Quantity),0) Quantity from stockout where productid=1 group by BranchId;
```

[image]

and i want to show the result like this

[image]

Comment: Did you tried Left join of both queries and a subtraction in outer query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For each individual Select query results, get an additional field, namely, **factor**. Its value will be **+1** for stock in, and **-1** for stockout.
- Combine the results of individual select queries using [Union All](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html), and utilize the resultset as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html).
- Now, simply do a Sum again, multiplying with the factor, on a grouping of BranchId.

Try the following query:

```
SELECT derived_t.BranchId, 
       SUM(derived_t.factor * derived_t.quantity) AS Quantity 
FROM 
(
 select BranchId, 
        ifnull(sum(Quantity),0) as quantity, 
        1 as factor 
 from stockin 
 where productid=1 
 group by BranchId

 UNION ALL 

 select BranchId, 
        ifnull(sum(Quantity),0) Quantity, 
        -1 as factor
 from stockout 
 where productid=1 
 group by BranchId
) AS derived_t 

GROUP BY derived_t.BranchId
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Save a lot of time for me.

Answer (score 1):

use left join between stockin and stockout ,here you need left join because you may have stockin but may not out

left join your 2 quires

```
select t1.branchId, t1.quantity - coalesce(t2.quantity,0) result
from (
    select BranchId, coalesce(sum(Quantity),0) Quantity 
    from stockin 
    where productid=1 
    group by BranchId
) t1 left join (
   Select BranchId, coalesce(sum(Quantity),0) Quantity 
   from stockout
   where productid=1 
   group by BranchId
) t2 on t1.BranchId = t2.BranchId

branchId    result
1            4
2           10
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c549d3/6

Comment: This will only return  rows if both stock in and stock out are available, use `left join` instead

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join between  the two query

```
select a.branchId, a.quantity - ifnull(b.quantity,0) result
from (
    select BranchId, ifnull(sum(Quantity),0) Quantity 
    from stockin 
    where productid=1 
    group by BranchId
) a left join (
   Select BranchId, ifnull(sum(Quantity),0) Quantity 
   from stockout
   where productid=1 
   group by BranchId
) b on a.BranchId = b.BranchId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select branchid, sum(quantity) total
from
(
select branchid,quantity from stockin
union all
select branchid, quantity*-1 from stockout
) x
group by branchid;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c549d3/1